# How to "add Maven nature" to existing netbeans project?

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jmonkeyengine

I know "adding Maven nature" is an Eclipse term.

Actually I want to add SOME dependencies from maven repository by editing `pom.xml` file. Is it possible? I want to remain a directory structure and other `JAR` tracking of a project intact.

The project is of jMonkey SDK.

Answer (score 2):

in netbeans there are no natures. Either the project is a maven project (by having a pom.xml file in project directory) or it's not. No matter what type, projects are just opened.

if your project is both ant based project (having nbproject/project.xml file and build script) and contains pom.xml, then the ant project takes priority and will be opened as ant project. No way to mix then. to load as maven project you will have to delete ant project related files and restart the IDE.

Comment: Then how to utilize `pom.xml` from `Ant` project? Or may be it is possible to make a separate `Maven` project and refer it from `Ant` project? I just want not to copy jars manually.

Comment: in ant projects (build.xml) you can use the maven ant tasks or ivy tasks. In the NetBeans IDE however there is only a single project in any given directory and ant projects cannot refer to maven projects.

Answer (score 1):

- add minimal `pom.xml` file
- close project
- re import it to netbeans as maven project
- or create a new minimal maven project and delete source and resource directories and place your project stsructure and
- configure pom.xml to match with your directory structure

  - by specifying resources & source directories in pom.xml

Comment: I am afraid it can break main jMonkey nature?

Comment: Sorry I need to do this in NetBeans, not Eclipse :)

Comment: I can't find importing of projects in NetBeans. Project can be closed or opened, not imported.

Comment: if yes just follow _or part_